# Render only takes seconds however result is incredibly blurry

Tags: rendering

When I render with Blender the render only takes a couple of seconds when I use the GPU even though it would take hours with the CPU. However the result comes out incredibly blurry. I have noticed that it gets to around sample 50 and then suddenly goes incredibly fast taking only around 4 seconds to reach sample 1000.

[image]

GPU: 980ti
CPU: i7 3820
Blender Ver: 3.2.2

Comment: Your noise threshold and denoising may be the issue, or you are rendering at 50% resolution or something

Comment: I tried using the blender default noise threshold and turning off denoising but nothing worked. Also tried blenders denoising. I might upload a clip of whats happening soon @AllenSimpson

Comment: @AllenSimpson I am rendering at 100% resolution. Heres a video of whats happening. This is with denosing off but its the same thing with it on. https://streamable.com/hd2i8i

Comment: Look at depth of field settings on your camera, you might want to [edit] these details into the question

Comment: A lot of guessing here :) probably better share some simplified file. BTW your threshold in video is not default, also you have enabled some kind of Simplification in properties, and you use Volumes that can also participate on issue :)